# HyperLedger Caliper Report Formatting issue

Tags: hyperledger-caliper

how can I increase the precision after the decimal point in Caliper report for max/min/avg latency? it gives me 0.1/0/0 repectively. I need it to be 0.1000/0.0000/0.0000. in order to get some values to plot.

Answer (score 0):

It's a configurable property with the default value defined here
https://github.com/hyperledger/caliper/blob/5ee6aaa61176d42f90dadb1970b1a1e4a1bfe2b8/packages/caliper-core/lib/common/config/default.yaml#L49

How to alter these values is documented here
https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper/v0.4.2/runtime-config/

but I would hope that if you supplied the following option when you launch caliper that would also work

```
--caliper-report-precision 5
```

as an example